# Find DISTINCT LAST record with SQL LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, window-functions

I'm running MySQL 5.6.
I have two related tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Cars (
    id INT NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT,
    plate VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    flag TINYINT,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
)
```

and:

```
CREATE TABLE Rents (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    out_date DATE NOT NULL,
    in_date DATE,
    car_id INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (car_id) REFERENCES Cars(id),
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
)
```

I can have multiple rents for each car (0 to many).

I need to select all vehicles in table `Cars` (with `flag = 1`) along with their *status* i.e. I need to know if each car is currently **unavailable** (only `out_date` is filled) or **availabe** (`out_date` and `in_date` filled) of course also vehicles without any rents are to be considered **available**.

The result set need to include **out_date** and **in_date** values [Update 17/07/2022].

I tought to use something like:

```
SELECT 
    *,
    IF(Rents.in_date IS NOT NULL AND Rents.out_date IS NOT NULL, 1, IF(Rents.id IS NULL, 1, 0)) AS status
FROM Cars 
LEFT JOIN Rents ON Cars.id = Rent.Car_id WHERE Cars.Flag = 1
```

but this of course will just return all the rows with positive flag match and a status evaluation (0 **unavailable**, 1 **available**):

```
id | plate    | flag | id | out_date  | in_date      | car_id | status
---------------------------------------------------------------------
'1', 'FA787MX', '1',  '1', '2022-07-14', '2022-07-15', '1',     '1'
'1', 'FA787MX', '1',  '2', '2022-07-16', NULL,         '1',     '0'
'3', 'AB124DF', '1',  '4', '2022-07-13', '2022-07-14', '3',     '1'
'4', 'CC666VC', '1',  NULL, NULL,        NULL,         NULL,    '1'
'5', 'GG435ED', '1',  '5', '2022-07-16', NULL,         '5',     '0'
```

While I need to have this (edited 17/07/2022):

```
'1', 'FA787MX', '1',  '2', '2022-07-16', NULL,         '1',     '0'
'3', 'AB124DF', '1',  '4', '2022-07-13', '2022-07-14', '3',     '1'
'4', 'CC666VC', '1',  NULL, NULL,        NULL,         NULL,    '1'
'5', 'GG435ED', '1',  '5', '2022-07-16', NULL,         '5',     '0'
```

i.e. only the second row of *FA787MX* car should be mantained since it's  the most recent **out_date** value (no matter if it's **id** is higher or lower).

For the sake of completeness: There is no guarantee that rental **ids** will be kept consistent with their rental history. In other words you cannot be sure that for a given car the rental where **in_date = NULL** is the correct one but you should compare them by **out_date** value.

---

Data sample:

```
INSERT INTO `Cars` (`id`, `plate`, `flag`) VALUES (1, 'FA787MX', 1); 
INSERT INTO `Cars` (`id`, `plate`, `flag`) VALUES (2, 'EX431YY', 0); 
INSERT INTO `Cars` (`id`, `plate`, `flag`) VALUES (3, 'AB124DF', 1); 
INSERT INTO `Cars` (`id`, `plate`, `flag`) VALUES (4, 'CC666VC', 1); 
INSERT INTO `Cars` (`id`, `plate`, `flag`) VALUES (5, 'GG435ED', 1); 

INSERT INTO `Rents` (`id`, `out_date`, `in_date`, `car_id`) VALUES (1, '2022-07-14', '2022-07-15', 1); 
INSERT INTO `Rents` (`id`, `out_date`, `in_date`, `car_id`) VALUES (2, '2022-07-16', NULL, 1); 
INSERT INTO `Rents` (`id`, `out_date`, `in_date`, `car_id`) VALUES (3, '2022-07-16', NULL, 2); 
INSERT INTO `Rents` (`id`, `out_date`, `in_date`, `car_id`) VALUES (4, '2022-07-13', '2022-07-14', 3); 
INSERT INTO `Rents` (`id`, `out_date`, `in_date`, `car_id`) VALUES (5, '2022-07-16', NULL, 5);
```

Comment: Be careful sorting by out_date if a car can be rented more than once in a day. If that is the column you want to sort on, using a full timestamp there would be safer.

Comment: @Jerry I cannot change any of the existing tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to join to find only those rentals that are still outstanding (in_date IS NULL).  That will drop the old rentals having in_date not null.

Based on the updated requirements, there are a few ways to do it.  One is a simple outer join to find the most recent rental per car to obtain the corresponding in_date as well...

[MySQL 5.6 fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=4053b564afa214710f56c6806e1b0008)

```sql
SELECT Cars.*
     , Rents.out_date
     , Rents.in_date
     , Rents.id IS NULL OR Rents.in_date IS NOT NULL AS status_final
  FROM Cars
  LEFT JOIN Rents
    ON Cars.id = Rents.Car_id
  LEFT JOIN Rents AS r2
    ON Rents.out_date < r2.out_date
   AND Rents.Car_id = r2.Car_id
 WHERE Cars.Flag = 1
   AND r2.Car_id IS NULL
 ORDER BY Cars.id
;
```

The result:

| id | plate | flag | out_date | in_date | status_final |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | FA787MX | 1 | 2022-07-16 |  | 0 |
| 3 | AB124DF | 1 | 2022-07-13 | 2022-07-14 | 1 |
| 4 | CC666VC | 1 |  |  | 1 |
| 5 | GG435ED | 1 | 2022-07-16 |  | 0 |

Based on the original requirements: Try this ([fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ae13cbb0389c580de571b255cf56c3a3)):

```sql
SELECT Cars.*
     , Rents.in_date
     , CASE WHEN in_date IS NOT NULL OR Rents.id IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS status_final
  FROM Cars 
  LEFT JOIN Rents
    ON Cars.id = Rents.Car_id
   AND in_date IS NULL
 WHERE Cars.Flag = 1
;
```

and if the results contain only those with in_date IS NULL, this reduces to:

```sql
SELECT Cars.*
     , out_date
     , Rents.in_date
     , Rents.id IS NULL AS status_final
  FROM Cars 
  LEFT JOIN Rents
    ON Cars.id = Rents.Car_id
   AND in_date IS NULL
 WHERE Cars.Flag = 1
;
```

Result:

| id | plate | flag | out_date | in_date | status_final |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | FA787MX | 1 | 2022-07-16 |  | 0 |
| 3 | AB124DF | 1 |  |  | 1 |
| 4 | CC666VC | 1 |  |  | 1 |
| 5 | GG435ED | 1 | 2022-07-16 |  | 0 |

Comment: I need **out_date**, and **in_date** to be filled also in the result set (while in this one the row related to **AB124DF** car has no values) also **in_date IS NULL** clause could be a source of problems. I added some details on the question please take them into account

Comment: @weirdgyn Yes. I see you changed the requirement.  I decided not to guess and only provided the columns requested.  Obtaining the other detail is not difficult.  Please add any other requirements / restrictions to the question.  It's important to know that you're using MySQL 5.6 (in the question).  That's a rather old version.

Comment: I just discovered that the production server was not aligned with my dev machine.. I hope they will update the production server but they are probably afraid of data loss

Answer (score 1):

If your version of MySql is 8.0+ use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to pick the latest row for each car in `Rents`:

```
SELECT c.*, r.*,
       r.out_date IS NULL OR r.in_date IS NOT NULL status
FROM Cars c 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY car_id ORDER BY out_date DESC) rn
  FROM Rents
) r ON r.car_id = c.id AND r.rn = 1
WHERE c.flag = 1;
```

For previous versions use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT c.*, r.*,
       r.out_date IS NULL OR r.in_date IS NOT NULL status
FROM Cars c 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT r1.*
  FROM Rents r1
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
              SELECT *
              FROM Rents r2
              WHERE r2.car_id = r1.car_id AND r2.out_date > r1.out_date
            )
) r ON r.car_id = c.id
WHERE c.flag = 1;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b004bb592e9fea5da36af40bf1186061).

Comment: There's an unexpected problem with your solution (that works as expected) ... I need to store it as a View but MySQL refuse to save it since it uses a subquery.

Comment: @weirdgyn the problem is not the subquery, but 2 columns with the same name `id` which you have in your expected results. Just use an alias for one of them: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=d661b9791aec92e7941b9d5d87e97200

Comment: @weirdgyn or:https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f381436b7cb24b6729800c97a52a2d71

Comment: the problem is in the production server it runs MySQL 5.6 and the error is clearly about subqueries... I tried aliasing fields but it keeps returning the same error. Saving it as a stored procedure made it work anyway...

Answer (score 0):

If you imagine the result of your query as a table, you can easily write a query that would give you what you need (the subquery is just yours with the select spelled out to give a unique column name to the second `id` column, as it seemed useful - the only way to uniquely identify a row):

```
SELECT MAX(rent_id) FROM (
    SELECT 
        Cars.id as id,
        plate,
        flag,
        Rents.id as rent_id,
        out_date,
        in_date,
        car_id,
        IF(Rents.in_date IS NOT NULL AND Rents.out_date IS NOT NULL, 1, IF(Rents.id IS NULL, 1, 0)) AS status
    FROM Cars 
    LEFT JOIN Rents ON Cars.id = Rents.car_id WHERE Cars.Flag = 1
) as rental_status
WHERE status = 0
GROUP BY car_id;
```

Which tells you which rows are interesting:

```
+--------------+
| MAX(rent_id) |
+--------------+
|            2 |
|            5 |
+--------------+
```

Now you can use a join to return the results of your initial query only for the interesting rows. To avoid having to spell out that query all over again, MySQL 8 has a way to stash the results of your core query and use it like a table:

```
WITH
  status_data AS (
    SELECT 
        Cars.id as id,
        plate,
        flag,
        Rents.id as rent_id,
        out_date,
        in_date,
        car_id,
        IF(Rents.in_date IS NOT NULL AND Rents.out_date IS NOT NULL, 1, IF(Rents.id IS NULL, 1, 0)) AS status
    FROM Cars 
    LEFT JOIN Rents ON Cars.id = Rents.car_id WHERE Cars.Flag = 1
)

SELECT * from status_data
JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(rent_id) as rent_id FROM status_data
    WHERE status = 0
    GROUP BY car_id
) as ids using(rent_id);
```

Giving the result:

```
+---------+----+---------+------+------------+---------+--------+--------+
| rent_id | id | plate   | flag | out_date   | in_date | car_id | status |
+---------+----+---------+------+------------+---------+--------+--------+
|       2 |  1 | FA787MX |    1 | 2022-07-16 | NULL    |      1 |      0 |
|       5 |  5 | GG435ED |    1 | 2022-07-16 | NULL    |      5 |      0 |
+---------+----+---------+------+------------+---------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: you're only keeping into account rents without **in_date** ... I added the correct result set in the answer pleasee look at it... this result just take into account only 'pending' rents i.e. only unavailable cars.

Comment: also removing `WHERE status = 0` will not produce the correct result set.